# Find diagonal of inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, projective-space, random-matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have computed the Cholesky of a positive semidefinite matrix $\Theta$. However, I wish to know the diagonal elements of the inverse of $\Theta^{-1}_{ii}$. Is it possible to do this using the Cholesky that I have computed? Or will finding the eigenvalues alone (without the orthonormal matrices of a SVD) help this cause? Are there any other suggestions or alternative decompositions that will aid finding the inverse matrix diagonal?

I've seen that **random projections** does wonders for inverting matrices. Could something like this be applied here?

Comment: I don't see why this question should be on hold. The subtext of the question seems to be clear and constitutes a non-trivial question: what is an optimal way to compute the diagonal elements of a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix? The naive way to compute the entire inverse is $O(n^3)$. But can one get just the diagonal with a smaller asymptotic exponent?

Comment: Not a solution of your problem. However Schur complement formula tells that $\frac{1}{(\Theta^{-1})_{ii}}=\Theta_{ii}-r_{i}\tilde\Theta^{-1}c_{i}$, where $r_{i}=(\Theta_{i1},\ldots,\hat\Theta_{ii},\ldots,\Theta_{in})$, $c_{i}=(\Theta_{1i},\ldots,\hat\Theta_{ii},\ldots,\Theta_{ni})$ ($\hat a$ means $a$ is removed), and $\tilde\Theta$ is obtained from $\Theta$ after removing $i$th row and $i$th Column.

Comment: The following question seems related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64420/is-there-a-faster-way-to-calculate-a-few-diagonal-elements-of-the-inverse-of-a-h

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled onto this question when trying to answer a similar question

**I want a diagonal matrix that best approximates the inverse of a matrix ${\bf B} \succ 0$.**

I'll post my answer to **that** question in case it helps other (and maybe OP).  In this case, "best" means nearest in the $\ell_2$ sense.

$$\textbf{d}^*(\textbf{B}) = \operatorname{argmin}_{\textbf{d}} \tfrac 1 2 \| \textbf{B} \operatorname{diag} (\textbf{d}) - \textbf{I} \|_F^2$$

This is separable in $d_i$ and differentiable.  Setting the gradient to zero brings us to the closed form (and very cheap) solution

$$[\textbf{d}^*]_i = \frac {b_{ii} } { \| \textbf{b}_i \|^2}$$

(Note in complex numbers, you'd need to conjugate)

I wouldn't be surprised if this has been known for 100 years, but I couldn't easily find it.

Comment: This is well-known and is called "sparse approximate inverse". These are generally used as preconditioners.

Comment: So not 100 years old, but more like 20 or so.  Thanks for commenting with the correct terminology.

Comment: What if $B$ is not posdef, not even symmetric: $\|b_i\|^2 \to \|b_{row\ i}\| \|b_{col\ i}\|$ ?  Would you have a test case or two ?

Comment: @denis , this was to cheaply approximate the inverse of a Gram matrix.  So B was always pos semidef. Adding epsilon to the diagonal elements makes it definite in practice.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Cholesky decomposition, you can easily compute the whole matrix inverse.  Since

$$\Theta = R^* R$$

where $R$ is upper-triangular, then you can find $\Theta^{-1}$ by solving

$$R^* R X = I$$

where $I$ is the identity.  The latter system can be solved by forward and backward substitution.

If you only want the diagonal entries of $X$, you could save perhaps half the computation by stopping the backward substitution process (for each column) when you get to the diagonal entry.

Comment: I guess that a more interesting answer would be a way to compute the just diagonal of the inverse in less than $O(n^3)$ time, is the same order as the time it takes to compute the entire inverse.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing all of this in Matlab. So doing for loops is worse than doing the actual inverse. But +1 regardless for the answer.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine but forward and backward substitutions are both $O(n^2)$?

Comment: @BenjaminChristoffersen but you have to solve with $n$ different right hand side vectors, so altogether it's $n^3$.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Tang and Saad have a method that uses random vectors (not necessarily projections):

[A Probing Method for Computing the Diagonal of the Matrix Inverse](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/umsi-2010-42.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I think that we cannot have a complexity $<n^3/3$. Indeed let $\Theta=LL^*$ where $L$ is lower triangular. Clearly $\Theta^{-1}={L^*}^{-1}L^{-1}$ ; let $L^{-1}=[u_{i,j}]$. Then (F)  ${\Theta^{-1}}_{i,i}=\sum_{j\geq i}|u_{j,i}|^2$. Then we must know the $(|u_{j,i}|)$ and (in my opinion) we must know the $(u_{j,i})$, that is $L^{-1}$. The complexity of the calculation of $L^{-1}$ is $\sim n^3/3$ (cf. [A Fast Triangular Matrix Inversion](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2012/WCE2012_pp100-102.pdf) by R. Mahfoudhi). Along the second step, the calculation of the $({\Theta^{-1}}_{i,i})$ (with (F)) is in $O(n^2)$.